# PowerShell File monitor at Windows startup

Tags: events, powershell, monitoring

I have a file system monitoring PowerShell script using `System.IO.FileSystemWatcher` events.
The script works great, but it requires an open PowerShell window.

Thus, I need to run it as a Windows Service at Windows startup (without logon). Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To execute your script at windows startup (without logon) you could create a windows service for it (using srvany.exe).
Steps:

1. Get the windows 2003 resource kit (which contains srvany.exe)
2. Install the resource kit
3. Create the service using sc and srvany.exe

   ```
   sc create PSService binPath= "C:\Program Files\Windows Resource Kits\Tools\srvany.exe" DisplayName= "PSService"
   ```
4. Parametrize your service

   ```
   Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
   [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\PSService]
   "Type"=dword:00000010
   "Start"=dword:00000003
   "ErrorControl"=dword:00000001
   "DisplayName"="PSService"
   "ObjectName"="LocalSystem"
   [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\PSService\Parameters]
   "Application"="C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe -noExit -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -File C:\\PSService\\psservice.ps1"
   ```

Some remarks:

- Srvany.exe is not available for Windows Vista and up. It might work, but it's probably not supported
- You might want to run it with other credentials (for security reasons)
- You might want to save your script in a directory where only administrators have write access  (for security reasons)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But this'll not solve my problem. Now monitoring is running in open PS window `$watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$watcher.Path = $searchPath
$watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true
$changed = Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Changed" -Action {....}`  Your decision just execute the PS code, it will not monitor the FS.

Comment: @Misko You should add the -noExit switch when launching powershell to avoid that the powershell process exits after running the script. I changed the .reg file in my answer.